# configure error: Could not link against boost_system

Tags: linux, boost, debian

I'm trying to install a package (soccer simulator 2d) on Debian. When I go to the directory and run `./configure`, I get the following:

```
reza@debian:~/soccer/rcssserver-15.0.1$ ./configure
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for g++... g++
checking whether the C++ compiler works... yes
checking for C++ compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking for gawk... (cached) mawk
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... (cached) yes
checking for cos in -lm... yes
checking for deflate in -lz... no
checking whether the compiler implements namespaces... yes
checking whether the compiler has stringstream... yes
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for working alloca.h... yes
checking for alloca... yes
checking for ANSI C header files... (cached) yes
checking arpa/inet.h usability... yes
checking arpa/inet.h presence... yes
checking for arpa/inet.h... yes
checking fcntl.h usability... yes
checking fcntl.h presence... yes
checking for fcntl.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... (cached) yes
checking libintl.h usability... yes
checking libintl.h presence... yes
checking for libintl.h... yes
checking for libintl.h... (cached) yes
checking malloc.h usability... yes
checking malloc.h presence... yes
checking for malloc.h... yes
checking netdb.h usability... yes
checking netdb.h presence... yes
checking for netdb.h... yes
checking netinet/in.h usability... yes
checking netinet/in.h presence... yes
checking for netinet/in.h... yes
checking poll.h usability... yes
checking poll.h presence... yes
checking for poll.h... yes
checking pwd.h usability... yes
checking pwd.h presence... yes
checking for pwd.h... yes
checking stddef.h usability... yes
checking stddef.h presence... yes
checking for stddef.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking sys/param.h usability... yes
checking sys/param.h presence... yes
checking for sys/param.h... yes
checking sys/socket.h usability... yes
checking sys/socket.h presence... yes
checking for sys/socket.h... yes
checking sys/time.h usability... yes
checking sys/time.h presence... yes
checking for sys/time.h... yes
checking for sys/types.h... (cached) yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking for stdbool.h that conforms to C99... yes
checking for _Bool... yes
checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes
checking for inline... inline
checking for int16_t... yes
checking for int32_t... yes
checking for int8_t... yes
checking for size_t... yes
checking whether time.h and sys/time.h may both be included... yes
checking whether struct tm is in sys/time.h or time.h... time.h
checking for uint16_t... yes
checking for uint32_t... yes
checking for uint8_t... yes
checking for socklen_t... yes
checking for size_t... (cached) yes
checking for pid_t... yes
checking vfork.h usability... no
checking vfork.h presence... no
checking for vfork.h... no
checking for fork... yes
checking for vfork... yes
checking for working fork... yes
checking for working vfork... (cached) yes
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for GNU libc compatible malloc... yes
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for GNU libc compatible realloc... yes
checking return type of signal handlers... void
checking for strftime... yes
checking for memset... yes
checking for floor... yes
checking for gethostbyname... yes
checking for gettimeofday... yes
checking for inet_ntoa... yes
checking for memset... (cached) yes
checking for mkdir... yes
checking for pow... yes
checking for rint... yes
checking for socket... yes
checking for sqrt... yes
checking for strdup... yes
checking for strerror... yes
checking for flex... flex
checking lex output file root... lex.yy
checking lex library... -lfl
checking whether yytext is a pointer... yes
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking if flex is the lexer generator... yes
checking for bison... bison -y
checking if bison is the parser generator... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... (cached) /bin/sed
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for ar... ar
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking dependency style of g++... (cached) gcc3
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... no
checking for ld used by g++... /usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) is GNU ld... yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking for g++ option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if g++ PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if g++ static flag -static works... yes
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking for boostlib >= 1.32.0... yes
checking whether the Boost::System library is available... yes
checking for exit in -lboost_system... no
configure: error: Could not link against boost_system
```

I have installed the boost library, so I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: Do you have something like `libboost-system1.46.1` installed as well? On my Ubuntu box, it's a separate package from just libboost.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

On a Debian based **64-bit** machine, the following command fixed this error for me:

```
  ./configure --with-boost-libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

Comment: To add some information somewhat later, this didn't solve the case on my linux box (ubuntu 16.04 based); had to install libboost-system1.54-dev instead (version matching the libboost dev package, of course).

Comment: On a Fedora based 64-bit machine:
--with-boost-libdir=/usr/lib64

Answer (score 21):

I **thought** I had it installed but

```
$ sudo apt-get install libboost1.48-*
```

fixed the problem for me by installing missing boost packages.

Comment: sudo apt-get install libboost1.55-all-dev helped me

Comment: Thanks! I tried every answer from this page but only this worked for me. Before, I installed by `sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev` but `.configure` couldn't find boost.

Comment: People from the future: **Check which version you install**, there may be a newer version available when you read this

Comment: Isn't there a metapackage for ubuntu that install the newest available, without specifying the version manually ? Yes: Ubuntu 16.04: `libboost-all-dev` (and no need to further specify the path in configure)

Answer (score 12):

In my case I was missing some necessary parts of boost. Try executing on Ubuntu/Debian:

`sudo apt-get install libboost-system-dev libboost-filesystem-dev libboost-chrono-dev libboost-program-options-dev libboost-test-dev libboost-thread-dev libboost-iostreams-dev`

Comment: I had to install also `libboost-iostreams-dev` (Ubuntu 20.04)

Answer (score 7):

On a Debian based 32-bit machine, the following command fixed this error for me:

```
./configure --with-boost-libdir=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
```

On a Debian based 64-bit machine, try the following command:

```
./configure --with-boost-libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

More info can be [found here.](https://github.com/miguelfreitas/twister-core/issues/91)

Comment: Problem solved, after following @oozie's post and followed this post. Though, I think the former was unnecessary.

Answer (score 4):

Check [this post](http://notes.benv.junerules.com/blast-its-boost-slackware64-and-deluge-libtorrent-rasterbar/). I had the same problem. I am on 64 Bit machine. You have to specify the path to the 64 bit libraries. I found this post which fixes the problem.

Answer (score 4):

I just had this issue and for the benefit of anyone else, make sure you look at the `configure` output very closely!  There is a bug in the checks, so if Boost library B is missing, you will see this:

```
checking whether the A library is available... yes
checking for exit in -lA... yes
checking whether the B library is available... no
configure: error: Could not link against A
```

Note that although the error message complains about `A`, the missing library is actually `B`!  If you install library `B` then the check will succeed.

Answer (score 2):

Just to let potential viewers know, use `./configure --with-boost-libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf` on armhf devices. Thanks to @Hadi for the inspiration.

Answer (score 2):

Installing

- libboost-system-dev
- libboost-filesystem-dev
- libboost-chrono-dev
- libboost-program-options-dev
- libboost-test-dev
- libboost-thread-dev
- libboost-iostreams-dev

Fixed the issue.  The report of ./configure is:

```
checking whether the Boost::System library is available... yes
checking for exit in -lboost_system... yes
checking whether the Boost::Filesystem library is available... yes
checking for exit in -lboost_filesystem... yes
checking whether the Boost::IOStreams library is available... yes
checking for exit in -lboost_iostreams... yes
checking whether the Boost::Program_Options library is available... yes
checking for exit in -lboost_program_options... yes
checking whether the Boost::Regex library is available... yes
checking for exit in -lboost_regex... yes
checking whether the Boost::Thread library is available... yes
checking for exit in -lboost_thread... yes
checking whether the Boost::Unit_Test_Framework library is available... yes
```

Comment: Actually, I need this to compile EPSON scanner driver

Answer (score 1):

No expert here, but my $.02:

First, Boost is only *mostly* a headers-only library.  For some libraries, you do have to build, and add to your lib path; boost_system is one of those libs.

Second, it's easy to overlook the fact that you can build the Boost libs as static libs, or as shared libs, and if you've built one and are trying to link against the other, that might account for your problem.

./b2 runtime-link=shared will create shared; ./b2 runtime-link=static will build static libs.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

```
install libboost-all-dev
```

resolved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue and adding the --with-boost-libdir=XXX did not work, however when I switched to gcc v9.3 everything compiled and the boost libraries linked in.

Check what version your boost library was compiled with and match the compiler version.. might help.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is to make sure there are `libboost_system.so*` in your system.

1. If not, you need to install `libboost_system` package and check again.

```bash
sudo apt install libboost-system${version_you_need}  # avoid version conflicts
```

2. If there is only `${prefix}/libboost_system.so.${version}` in the system, you need to create a link called `libboost_system.so` to it.

```bash
sudo ln -s ${prefix}/libboost_system.so.${version} ${prefix}/libboost_system.so
```

3. Depending on the path where the library is, you may need to pass it to `configure` via `--with-boost-libdir` as mentioned in other answers.