# ./configure error: Could not find any version boost_system to link to

Tags: configure

I am trying to install a package (portcullis) via linux. However, when I run ./configure I get the following error:

```
checking whether the Boost::System library is available... yes
configure: WARNING: Could not find a dynamic version of boost_system
configure: WARNING: Could not find a static version of boost_system
configure: error: Could not find any version boost_system to link to
```

I have tried various things suggested here: [configure error: Could not link against boost_system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132335/configure-error-could-not-link-against-boost-system). However, nothing worked for me e.g: sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev

Any help would be most appreciated. Thanks

Comment: sorry, forgot to mention that libboost-all-dev is already the newest version.

Comment: Maybe you will have better answer on serverfault, it's more of a configuration question then programming.

Comment: apologies; thank you for this advice

Comment: @LouisLoudogTrottier This doesn't look appropriate for [sf].

Comment: So many StackExchange, must be one that is appropriate for this question. Mind me, http://superuser.com